# Where should I declare 2 varable in map method in react

Tags: reactjs

**How can I run 2 variable in a map method**

*I trying this way, but not  working*

```
      <table>
      <tbody>
         {[addEnglish,addKannada].map((data)=>{
           return(
             <tr>
               <td>{data.addEnglish}</td>
               <td>{data.addKannada}</td>
             </tr>
           )
         })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What do you want to see exactly

Comment: Does your data contain `addEnglish` and `addKannada`? Learn more about the `map` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Also include other parts of code (which are sufficiently detailed) so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't array for this, but if you have multiple values and you want both in 1 row then you have to use an array of objects like below.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {[{ addEnglish, addKannada }].map((data) => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{data.addEnglish}</td>
          <td>{data.addKannada}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>;
```